# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta en "Desde el principio él *tuvo / tenía* muchos amigos"?

Tags: pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

> Desde el principio él **tuvo / tenía** muchos amigos y siempre salía con ellos los fines de semana.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos formas son correctas. Normalmente el pretérito perfecto simple se refiere a una acción puntual en el pasado, a diferencia del pretérito imperfecto, que describe una acción durativa o habitual:

- El fin de semana **salí** con amigos.
- Los fines de semana **salía** con amigos.

No obstante, con el verbo "tener" y otros verbos estáticos, no dinámicos, la diferencia -- si es que existe -- no es tan clara.

1. Desde el principio él **tuvo** muchos amigos y siempre salía con ellos los fines de semana.
2. Desde el principio él **tenía** muchos amigos y siempre salía con ellos los fines de semana.

El adverbial "desde el principio" vuelve más similares ambos verbos. Si cambiamos por "al principio", (1) parecería indicar que él tuvo amigos (o inclusive se hizo de amigos) en ese momento, mientras que (2) podría sugerir que el ya tenía amigos de antes.

Nota: Si tu lengua materna es el portugués, la diferencia entre ambos (si la hay) sería análoga a la diferencia entre *teve* y *tinha*.

Comment: +1 en este caso creo que tiendo más hacia el imperfecto por simetría con  *salía*

Comment: @guifa Pensé en una razón estilística, pero realmente no encuentro demasiada diferencia, ni tampoco la conveniencia o necesidad de un paralelismo entre ambos verbos.

Comment: Yo me inclinaría más por *tuvo* si comenzamos diciendo *Desde el principio*, quizá porque se trata de un punto fijo específico en el tiempo. Pero es una impresión mía nomás.

Comment: @guifa - Dijiste +1 pero se te olvidó votar....

Answer (score 0):

Las dos formas se pueden usar, dependiendo si el contexto pinta el cuadro de algo que llegó a un fin bien definido, o si se trata de un hábito que ha continuado.

*Ejemplo de la primera forma:* Mi difunto hermano era extremadamente extrovertido, sobre todo en el periodo de sus estudios de licenciatura.  **Tuvo muchos amigos** y solía juntarse con ellos los fines de semana.

*Ejemplo de la segunda forma:* Cuando mi hijo era pequeño era muy extrovertido.  **Tenía muchos amigos** y conocidos entre la población de nuestra pequeña ciudad.  Por todos lados, muchísima gente lo saludaba, y él siempre me podía decir cómo se llamaban y cómo se habían conocido.